# Holt-Winters for multi-seasonal forecasting in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, forecasting, outliers, holtwinters

My data: I have two seasonal patterns in my hourly data... daily and weekly. For example... each day in my dataset has roughly the same shape based on hour of the day. However, certain days like Saturday and Sunday exhibit increases in my data, and also slightly different hourly shapes.

(Using holt-winters, as I found discovered here: https://gist.github.com/andrequeiroz/5888967)

I ran the algorithm, using 24 as my periods per season, and forecasting out 7 seasons (1 week), I noticed that it would over-forecast the weekdays and under-forecast the weekend since its estimating the saturday curve based on fridays curve and not a combination of friday's curve and saturday(t-1)'s curve. What would be a good way to include a secondary period in my data, as in, both 24 and 7? Is their a different algorithm that I should be using?

Answer (score 3):

One obvious way to account for different shapes would be to use just one sort of period, but make it have a periodicity of 7*24, so you would be forecasting the entire week as a single shape.

Have you tried linear regression, in which the predicted value is a linear trend plus a contribution from dummy variables? The simplest example to explain would be trend plus only a daily contribution. Then you would have

Y = X*t + c + A*D1 + B*D2 + ... F * D6 (+ noise)

Here you use linear regression to find the best fitting values of X, c, and A...F. t is the time, counting up 0, 1, 2, 3,... indefinitely, so the fitted value of X gives you a trend. c is a constant value, so it moves all the predicted Ys up or down. D1 is set to 1 on Tuesdays and 0 otherwise, D2 is set to 1 on Wednesdays and 0 otherwise... D6 is set to 1 on Sundays and 0 otherwise, so the A..F terms give contributions for days other than Mondays. We don't fit a term for Mondays because if we did then we could not distinguish the c term - if you added 1 to c and subtracted one from each of A..F the predictions would be unchanged.

Hopefully you can now see that we could add 23 terms to account for an shape for the 24 hours of each day, and a total of 46 terms to account for a shape for the 24 hours of each weekday and the different 24 hours of each weekend day.

You would be best to look for a statistical package to handle this for you, such as the free R package (http://www.r-project.org/). It does have a bit of a learning curve, but you can probably find books or articles that take you through using it for just this sort of prediction.

Whatever you do, I would keep on checking forecasting methods against your historical data - people have found that the most accurate forecasting methods in practice are often surprisingly simple.